# Have Jenkins read the first column from a table in Confluence

Tags: jenkins, automation, confluence

I have to do a server-deployment on a weekly base which i am trying to automate as much as possible. Right now i am stuck, because i get some information from my companies confluence page where a few scripts are listed ordered by version.

As i already have some automation going in jenkins i wanted to try to get jenkins to read from this confluence page and have it execute e.g. all scripts from the 3.5.2 version in a step.

Can i somehow get information out of confluence with jenkins? Right now i do this manually every time. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a script in jenkins

1. Do a wget call in your jenkins script to call the confluence REST API to get the content of your page
2. Use jq to parse the content that comes back from confluence.
3. Parse the field you want and get the scripts you want
4. If you're feeling happy, you can even update your confluence page and say that your jenkins job ### ran these scripts.

I have created a blog on something similar:
http://javamemento.blogspot.no/2016/05/jira-confluence-3.html

There is some code in github too, if you're interested.

Comment: The part where i update the confluence page is a feature that i am planning as well, as i also have to check off the scripts in confluence after running them, i will automate this as well. Your answer helped me out, thank you!